# Is it possible to save Rulers ON and Grid ON as a part of Illustrator Workspace

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Creating a new file in Illustrator I should always press Command+R and Command+' to enable rulers and grid.

Is there any way to show them automatically on opening or to save them ON in a workspace/template (I've tried but with no success).

Illustrator version is CS6

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as I know, you actually can create a new template with grid and rulers set up, save it and then create every new file through "New From Template" action in the File menu. It works.

You can't define this setting as a part of some workspace.

Comment: you are right. i've create a template as you advise and it works. accepted